# How to set up SPF, DKIM and DMARC when using a different email provider?

Tags: spf, dkim, mx-record, dmarc

I have a domain, let's say, example.com hosted on a provider (fast comet). The A record points to a specific and external IP where a website is hosted and the MX record points to an external email provider (it points to example.com.mx.one.com).

The problem is, I currently need to create the SPF, DKIM and DMARC records so we can validate a mailing list service use of the example.com domain.

On the fast comet Cpanel, I don't have any SPF nor TXT record BUT on `dig txt example.com` I get
`;; ANSWER SECTION: example.com.    38400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.mailhostbox.com"`

On fast comet's CPanel Email deliverability tab I have the following message for both SPF and DKIM:

> “SPF” is not properly configured for this domain. To properly
> configure your SPF record, you must include the following mechanisms:
> This system does not control DNS for the “example.com” domain. You can
> install the suggested “SPF” record locally. However, this server is
> not the authoritative nameserver. If you install this record, this
> change will not be effective. Contact the person responsible for the
> “ns4.mysafedns.com”, “ns3.mysafedns.com”, “ns1.mysafedns.com”, and
> “ns2.mysafedns.com” nameservers and request that they update the “SPF”
> record with the following...

I already checked and those nameservers belong to fast comet and are the default ones.

I am at a loss for what should I do. I already did this procedure on a domain that is on fast comet as well (and has the same nameservers) but uses fast comet's email service and it all went well.

How/Where can I create these records? Where is that SPF record stored if I can't see it on either fast comet nor one.com's panel?

Comment: Why are you using `redirect`? You probably want an `include` mechanism to pull in your provider's SPF into yours instead, like `v=spf1 a mx include=_spf.mailhostbox.com ~all`.

Comment: Correct! The thing is, I can't find that SPF record, it is not on fast comet's CPanel nor on One.com's panel either. Whenever I try to create a correct SPF record using the include I need, it does not take any effect, it doesn't overwrite that ghost record that I can't find anywhere.

Comment: Well, `_spf.mailhostbox.com` serves a perfectly reasonable SPF record; I'd check that your own DNS is actually serving your lookups properly.